# send url in form params guzzle http

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I use laravel and GuzzleHttp for send post request same as following

```
$client = new Client(['verify' => false]);

$data = [
   'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'code',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                ],
  'form-params' => [
                        'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost',
                        'code' => 'MZTADnFF6m'
                ]
        ];

  $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://oom.com', $data);
```

but my problem is `'http://localhost'` send as `'http:\/\/localhost'` to api server

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: use urlencode with URL

urlencode("http://localhost")

Comment: @Rohit It gives me an error when the redirect_uri parameter is sent incorrectly

Comment: Please specify the error. what is an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stripslashes()` for achieve this. You can try

```
stripslashes("http:\/\/localhost");
```

it will resultd in

```
http://localhost
```

as a result

Answer (score 0):

use urlencode
here it is

```
'redirect_uri' => urlencode('http://localhost'),
```

Comment: whenever we pass URL in form or as a query string 
it adds backslash after every forward slash like
'http://localhost' **to** 'http:\/\/localhost'
in Python there is proper way to convert URL to string encoded that can be used on server side as well.
Above is the solution

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it